# Efficient development for modifying AOSP framework.jar

Tags: android, build, frameworks, android-source

I'd like to know if it's necessary to rebuild and redeploy my whole AOSP tree after I make modifications to Java source files in framework.jar.

I have working (buildable) trees os ICS and JellyBean and can successfully install them onto my virtual machine.

I'm aware about CCACHE to help speed up builds, and I imagine if I'm modifying C/C++ code then a rebuild and reinstall of the whole tree is my only option.

However, for small changes, such as one of the view or activity source files, is there a quicker method available? A rebuild and reinstall each time makes development a slow and painful process. I'm sure vendors and what not have faster methods at their disposal.

I had no luck with this method:

1. Running mm in frameworks/base (compiled successfully) and replacing the framework.jar/framework.odex files on the running system.
2. Rebooted - but then the system hung before the boot screen.
3. I tested my code by rebuilding the whole image and reinstalling and that image booted okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me I discovered the following way. However, I develop for a real device, thus, maybe my approach is not applicable for your case.

1. As you do, `mmm frameworks/base -jN` (if you want to add changes
   also to image and build image you can add `snod` but this will slow
   down the build process)
2. Run adb remount (to make system image writable) - you need to do
   this only once after you reflash all the device.
3. Run `adb sync system`

Comment: After running first step: No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE foo

Comment: You need to initialize your repository. It seems that the error says that you've not initialized it. Try at first build an image normally.